# Exception if there is IBOutlet in view controller created by initWithNibName

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

When I create a Navigation-based application, the second view controller is created with initWithNibName, if I add a label onto the second view and connect it with IBOutlet in the second view controller. After I navigate to the second view by clicking table cell, and then back to the root view, the application aborts - send message retainCount to a freed object.

I know this is caused by the IBOutlet label, which is retained, set nil in viewDidUnload and dealloc in dealloc. But I don't know why, and if I wanna still use IBOutlet, what can I do? Not dealloc it in viewcontroller's dealloc?

Anybody could help? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

holy crap, I think I didn't notice that I should release IBOutlets in view controller's dealloc rather than dealloc them.